# Need advice on scrolling layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

i am currently working on a sample for a lib that i wrote,designed to execute WebRequests such as `POST and GET` safely. At the moment i am trying to figure out a way to show the `response` of the request (Usually, HTML text) in my window.

It does not need to be fancy,but i thought about a Textblock that can scroll,but i can't seem to make mine works.

Here is what i am trying:

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="439" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="546,19,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="Scroller">
         <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" Width="433"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="block" Height="440" />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

What happens is that my content scrolls,but it does not appears fully in the window,it gets cut for some reason and i can't see all of the return.

Any other advice of how to do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Height of the TextBlock is fixed at 440. You should remove that.

Answer (score 1):

You have way too many hard-coded sizes, remove the `Width` and `Height` of the `TextBlock`. If you want it to scroll you need to allow it to take all the space it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Your scrollviewer is handling the scrolling and that is what requires the fixed height, as @Erno said the TextBlock within is also fixed height and it shouldn't be.

The content within the ScrollViewer should be as high as it needs to be, the ScrollViewer will handle the scrolling of that based on it's own height.